# login validation using php

Tags: php, validation, authentication

I'm trying to make a login form in PHP and have produced this so far:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username='';
$password='';
$userinfo = array(
        'user1'=>'password1',
        'user2'=>'password2'
    );

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '';
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid Username OR Password';
        //Invalid Login
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if($_SESSION['username']): ?>
        <p>Welcome <font color="#91b929"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']?></font></p>
        <p><a href="?logout=1">Logout</a></p>
    <?php else: ?>

    <form name="login" action="" method="post">
        Username:  <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
        Password:  <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is working fine when I am giving the wrong password, but when I am giving the wrong username it shows the following error:

> Undefined index: dfg in F:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\seesion\checklogin.php on line 17

Comment: what is the error it gives you?
and also trying to do this `$userinfo[$_POST['username']]` won't give the user password if it was different that 'user1' or 'user2'.
try this:
`if(isset($_POST['username'])&&!empty($_POST['username'])){
  $login=$_POST['username'];
  foreach($userinfo as $key => $value){
   if($login==$value) echo 'nice login!';
   else echo "Bad login!";
  }
}`

Comment: I think your code working properly. Can you describe what you want to get as result?

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki  i am getting the following error when i enter a wrong username   ==>>  :                                                                        Undefined index: dfg in F:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\seesion\checklogin.php on line 17

Comment: @alexeypalamar my code works when i enter the correct username password, i want to give a error message as 'Invalid Username OR Password' when the username is incorrect

Comment: @Mohit `$userinfo[$_POST['username']]` the error is here as i told you if you enter a wrong username it won't find it in the array as it will return an error not even false, so change it as i gave you in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple:

when you are entering the data in the form

```
username 
password
```

after clicking submit the program runs into

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
}
```

in this function it check the username is match to password or not

if both match to each other  it create a `session`

if does not match it create a error report and this program showing the error report

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add `die;` after the comment "//Invalid Login" to kill the script from executing the logged in panel.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you've already created `$username` and `$password` variables at the start of your script you can check if the `$_POST[]` variables are set and update them if so.

```
$username = ( isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : NULL );
$password = ( isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL );
```

Then you can use the shorter `$username` and `$password` variables in the rest of your script.
You need to check that both the `$username` and `$password` variables are not empty. And whether the `$username` exists as an `index` in your array (do this with the `isset($userinfo[$username])` before checking if the password is equal.

```
if( !empty($username) && !empty($password) ) {
    if( isset($userinfo[$username]) && $userinfo[$username] == $password ) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid Username OR Password';
        //Invalid Login
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

what is the error it gives you? and also trying to do this `$userinfo[$_POST['username']]` won't give the user password if it was different that `'user1' or 'user2'`. 
**try this:**

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])&&!empty($_POST['username'])){   
$login=$_POST['username'];
foreach($userinfo as $key => $value){
if($login==$value) echo 'nice login!';
else echo "Bad login!";
}
}
```